# Using Prismatic Schema and Core.Typed at the same time?

Tags: clojure, plumatic-schema, clojure-core.typed

I'm experimenting with these two libraries. I am able to use one or the other on their own, but when I try to use both at the same time (i.e., in the same file) I get an *extremely large* console error that complains about numerous prismatic schema library functions not being properly annotated. Is there a way to make core.typed ignore the schema stuff?